# Closed subscheme of an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is regarding Exercise 3.11 (b) in Harsthorne. I am unable to understand the hint given in the book, for it seems in the hint $Y$ is assumed to a SUBSET OF X, while the definition of closed subscheme involves homeomorphism of $Y$ onto a closed subset of $X$. Please clarify this, and in addition, if you can offer a 'hint' to prove the first part of the hint in the textbook, I am thankful.

Comment: Or slightly more precisely, any space that maps homeomorphically onto a closed subset may be identified with that closed subset.

Answer (score 0):

To echo Remy: as topological spaces you can identify the domain of a closed immersion with its image, and use that map to transfer the structure sheaf over to make everything airtight. The same sort of confusion can come up when you talk about submanifolds in differential geometry: do they have to be subsets or just manifolds with nice embeddings into our ambient manifold?

As a hint for the hint: it's good to think about the games with principal open subsets that are implicit in the proof of (3.2). Any point $P \in Y$ is contained in an affine open neighborhood $V$ in $Y$. Take an $f \in A$ such that $P \in D(f) \cap Y \subseteq V$.